# Removing webviews from parent views crashes app on iOS 10

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

With the recent upgrade to iOS 10 and Titanium SDK 5.5.1.GA, my app crashes when 
trying to remove a webview from a parent view. The webview loads the HTML correctly but when trying to go back the app fails.

Code:

```
    var aItems = view.children; //<- fails on this line if parent view has a webview child
    for( var i = aItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {

        aItems[ i ].backgroundImage = "";
        aItems[ i ].image = "";
        view.remove( aItems[ i ] );
        aItems[ i ] = null;
    }
```

Error:

```
    error   10:37:52.693612 -0500   NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1001
    default 10:37:52.851682 -0500   invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
```

Version:

```
    Operating System
      Name                        = Mac OS X
      Version                     = 10.12
      Architecture                = 64bit
      # CPUs                      = 8
      Memory                      = 8589934592
    Node.js
      Node.js Version             = 5.11.1
      npm Version                 = 3.8.6
    Titanium CLI
      CLI Version                 = 5.0.9
    Titanium SDK
      SDK Version                 = 5.5.1.GA
      Target Platform             = iphone
```

This only fails on iOS, not Android.

UPDATE:
If I do not set any HTML to the webview, the app works fine. I am getting the html remotely and then setting it on the webview.

Comment: If you can reproduce this error in a standalone app, it is most likely a bug. Which should be reported in the Appcelerator Jira: https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa
If you do, link ticket in comments here!

Comment: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-4560 <-- made a jira ticket for issue

Answer (score 0):

You could null the children before:

```
for(var i in view.children) view.children[i] = null;
```

Now you have two ways that you could try:

1) use the "removeAllChildren" method instead of do the loop and remove?

```
view.removeAllChildren();
```

2) try to set the views property to an empty array after nulling it's children:

```
view.children = [];
```

Either way, I think this is a platform bug, you should create a [JIRA Ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa)

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know if it works or not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't fix the problem. I ended up building a test app and was still able to create the problem. I am putting in a jira ticket for bug. Thanks for your help.